# Отключить вывод текста от библиотек в Python

Tags: python, input, консоль

Делаю парсер на python и мне не нравится что он выводит в консоль то что я не писал. Типа такого:

```
Looking for [chromedriver 78.0.3904.105 win32] driver in cache 
File found in cache by path 
[C:\Users\user1\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\78.0.3904.105\win32\chromedriver.exe]

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64414/devtools/browser/0f331df3-e795- 
2dbc- b181-0eas706c1edc
```

Как запретить библиотекам писать что-то в консоль?

Comment: Смотреть документацию библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Убрал большинство, с помощью:

```
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
#INFO = 0(по умолчанию), 
#WARNING = 1, 
#LOG_ERROR = 2, 
#LOG_FATAL = 3.
```